# checkbox in flutter isn't working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool _isChecked = false;
```

```
 CheckboxListTile(

                   title: const Text('Female'),
                   secondary: const Icon(Icons.female),
                   controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                   value: _isChecked,
                   onChanged: (value) {
                   setState(() => _isChecked = value!);
                   },
                 ),
```

I am trying to add a checkbox in Flutter but it isn't working correctly.

I tired on a android emulator and in windows also.

None of them worked

I even tried this

```
 Checkbox(
                   value: _isChecked,
                   onChanged: (value) {
                   setState(() => _isChecked == value);
                   },
                 ),
```

after that I add the _isChecked out side the build.

```
class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  bool _isChecked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

But still it doesn't work. Am I doing a simple mistake.

Or is there a wrong with my emulator.

Comment: _"it isn't working correctly"_ What _exacty_ is the problem?

Comment: When I run your code, the checkbox _is_ updated. Please share your full code.

Comment: *it doesn't work* is a meaningless, useless problem description. What **specifically** isn't working? What is the actual problem you're having? You should review [ask] and then come back and [edit] your post to be more specific about the issue you're having.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I managed to it get working

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working

Here is the code

```
class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  bool? _isChecked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

```
 CheckboxListTile(
                   title: const Text('Female'),
                   secondary: const Icon(Icons.female),
                   controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                   value: _isChecked,
                   onChanged: (_value) {
                      setState(() => _isChecked = _value);
                   },
           ),
```